# rsync command only copying 1kb system file; Missing data

Tags: linux, rsync

I am currently trying to copy data off of a linux filesystem onto a USB hard drive using rsync and am having an issue. The destination is only showing a system file of size 1KB. Here is sysntax for the command I am running with all the flags and such.

```
rsync -av --progress /folder/data /mnt/usb/backup/
```

When I "ls" the destination I can see all the files that would be in data but if I unmount the disk and plug it into a windows machine I only see a 1KB system file. The usb hard drive is formated as NTFS which I believe is compatible with both operating systems.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas as to what might be my issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing a trailing slash on the source directory. Yay

Comment: Yes, always remember `rsync -r /foo bar` copies `foo` recursively to `bar/foo` and `rsync -r /foo/ bar` copies the *contents* of `foo` (recursively) to `bar`...